# How to troubleshoot why zathura doesn't follow web links?

Tags: arch-linux, i3, browser, zathura, links

I'm pretty sure that once I was able to

1. press <kbd>f</kbd>,
2. then enter a number,
3. finally hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>,

and the link opened in the browser (I use [qutebrowser](https://github.com/qutebrowser/qutebrowser/)).

This doesn't seem to work anymore, in that following the procedure above, step 3. doesn't trigger any reaction in the browser, just like I've done nothing at all.

Unfortunately, I don't know since when, so I'd like some help in troubleshooting it.

On the other hand, in-document links are followed just fine, so I think that zathura simply doesn't know (anymore) what application to forward those links to.

Fwiw, I use i3 as window manager, no desktop manager.

Comment: Can you open the file in another viewer and make sure the links are actually linked and not just formatted like a link?

Comment: @stefan0xC, if I open the PDF in the browser, then the links do work.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Because I noticed a difference between Firefox and Chromium, i.e. Chromium would render links that Firefox (and Zathura) did not.

Comment: @stefan0xC, I'm using qutebrowser, as written in the original question. However, I'd tend to think it's not a rendering problem, for the reason I've added right now to the question.